# How do subgroups of the inner automorphisms of a group look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group, nilpotent-groups

I'm trying to prove the following proposition:

> Let $G$ be a group. Then $G$ is nilpotent iff ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is nilpotent.

I've proven that if $G$ is nilpotent then ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is nilpotent as well by showing that there exists a central series of ${\rm Inn}(G)$ where each element is of the form:

$${\rm Inn}_{G_{i}}(G):=\{f: x\mapsto hxh^{-1}\mid h\in G_i\}.$$

Now for the other direction, I assume that ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is nilpotent which means there exists a central series of it. But I don't how subgroups of ${\rm Inn}(G)$ look like. Are they all of the form I listed above? If not, what could they look like?

Note: We may not use the fact that $G$ is nilpotent $\Rightarrow G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent.

Comment: You can just take the pre-images of groups appearing in the central series of $\mathrm{Inn}(G)\simeq G/Z(G)$ under the map $G\rightarrow G/Z(G)$ and add $\{1\}\leq Z(G)$ in the left.

Comment: @Erica thank you, that sounds promising. I will try. However, for other people coming across this question, I'm still interested in understanding the form of subgroups of Inn(G).

Comment: The subgroups of $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ are in bijection with subgroups of $G$ containing the center $Z(G)$ by the correspondence theorem. So I don't know what do you mean by "the form of subgroups". I think they are all of the form $\mathrm{Inn}_{H}(G)=\mathrm{Inn}_{HZ(G)}(G)\simeq (HZ(G))/Z(G)$ as you listed.

Comment: @Erica thanks, that what I was looking for. I'll be happy to accept your reply if you post is as an answer (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the inner automorphism group $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ is isomorphic to the quotient $G/Z(G)$, the subgroups of $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ are in bijection with subgroups of $G$ containing $Z(G)$.

Given a central series of $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ of finite length, we can obtain a central series from $Z(G)$ to $G$, and thus a central series of $G$ by adding $\{1\}\triangleleft Z(G)$ to the left side. This shows that $G$ is also nilpotent.